# proftpd - Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, ssl, tls, proftpd

I'm trying to configure a FTP proftpd server with TLS in Ubuntu 16.04

I'm using proftpd from the proftpd-basic ubuntu package, which has tls_mod module compiled as shared module:

```
$ sudo proftpd -vv | grep mod_tls
  mod_tls_memcache/0.1
  mod_tls/2.6
```

I try to connect from a filezilla FTP client with the option "Use explicit FTP over TLS if available", but I get the following message establishing the connection

```
Status: Connecting to X.X.X.X:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: **Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.**
Status: Logged in
```

I've generated a self-signed certificate

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1541 ene  4 20:07 /etc/ssl/certs/proftpd.crt
-rw------- 1 root root 1708 ene  4 20:07 /etc/ssl/private/proftpd.key
```

and my configuration file has the following directives:

```
<IfModule mod_tls.c>
    TLSEngine                               on
    TLSLog                                  /var/log/proftpd/tls.log
    TLSProtocol                             SSLv23
    TLSRSACertificateFile                   /etc/ssl/certs/proftpd.crt
    TLSRSACertificateKeyFile                /etc/ssl/private/proftpd.key
    TLSVerifyClient                         off
    TLSRequired                             on
    TLSRenegotiate                          required on
</IfModule>
```

Is something wrong in my configuration?

EDIT:
this is what I see in the proftpd logfile (no sign of TLS)

```
2017-01-04 20:57:33,981 minimal proftpd[1947] 192.168.1.49 (192.168.1.10[192.168.1.10]): FTP session opened.
2017-01-04 20:57:36,302 minimal proftpd[1947] 192.168.1.49 (192.168.1.10[192.168.1.10]): USER direccion: Login successful.
```

Comment: Fixed. The user I was connecting with belonged to a Virtualhost and was not affected by the TSL directives in the configuration. I added the Global tag in the conf file and it's working now

Comment: Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user I was connecting with belonged to a Virtualhost and was not affected by the TSL directives in the configuration. I added the <global> tag in the tls.conf file and it's working now

Comment: I'm sorry, where does the <global> tag go in that file? Can you post the whole config file?